# nginx simple rewrite rules with php fastcgi

Tags: php, url-rewriting, nginx, fastcgi

I have nginx running on a VPS (php fastcgi) and want do be able to remove .php from the files names.

So instead of *index.php* showing up, **/** shows up

or instead of *contact.php*, **/contact/** shows up (notice the slash at the end)

Same thing for sub directories.

Is there a really super simple way to do this?

One of my bigger headaches has been to understand the .htaccess (apache) vs .conf (nginx)

If I have mydomain.com/  and put a .conf file, will nginx recognize it?  meaning if I do this:

/home/mydomain.com/myconfig.conf   will nginx recognize it?

Comment: search 'mod rewrite' one of the most asked questions on SO

Comment: do you intend to use sub directories, like `/contact/us/` to `contact/us.php` for example ? or are all links going to be just root level files ?

Comment: this is a good point: [wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)

Comment: yes I intend to create sub directories

Comment: example: `index  index.php index.html index.htm; rewrite ^/([A-Za-z]+)$ /contact.php/;`

Comment: [htaccess to nginx converter](http://winginx.com/htaccess)

Comment: this is what I came up with so far:  `code`# nginx configuration  

location / {  
 try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;  
 rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;  
}     `code`      seems to work although I'm wondering if there are any pitfalls.